# TypeError on matching pattern with module "re"

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I'm trying to extract the price of the item from my programme by parsing the HTML with help of "bs4" BeautifulSoup library

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Nokia-Lumia-1020-Nokia-Phone-41MP-Camera-Dual-Core-1-5GHz-32GB-ROM-2-GB/32415650302.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.67455f99ocHZOB&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10342_10343_10059_10340_10341_10696_100031_10084_10083_10103_524_10618_10624_10307_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_43,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=a182685b-0e22-4a88-a7be-6a51dfbeac21-3&algo_pvid=a182685b-0e22-4a88-a7be-6a51dfbeac21&priceBeautifyAB=0")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
element = soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"price", "id":"j-sku-price","class":"p-price"},text= not None)
pattern_1 = re.compile("/d+./d+").findall(element).text.strip()
print(pattern_1)
print(element)
```

and here is what I get as output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Visual_Studio_Files/Python_sample.py", line 9, in <module>
    pattern_1 = (re.compile("/d+./d+").findall(str_ele)).text.strip()
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Probably, you need `results = []`, => `for x in element:`, => `results.extend(re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', x.text))`

Comment: but if there is a digit in the html id tag this will also take that as a part of price

Answer (score 0):

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) freaks out because your `element` variable has the type `bs4.element.Tag`.

You can find this out by adding `print(type(element))` in your script.
Based on some quick poking around, I think you can extract the string you need from the tag using the `contents` attribute (which is a list) and taking the first member of this list (index `0`).

Moreover, `re.findall` also returns a list, so instead of `.text` you need to use `[0]` to access its first member. Thus you will once again have a string which supports the `.strip()` method!

Last but not least, it seems you may have mis-typed your slashes and meant to use `\` instead of `/`.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
pattern_1 = re.findall("\d+.\d+", element.contents[0])[0].strip()
```

This is definitely not pretty or very pythonic, but it will get the job done.
Note that I dropped the call to `re.compile` because that gets run in the background when you call `re.findall` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ilia Kurenkov this help me and i've also found new solution by altering this line of code :)

Comment: 'element = soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"price", "id":"j-sku-price","class":"p-price"}).text.strip()'

Comment: and removing the reguler expresion completly :)

Answer (score 0):

here is what it finally look like :)

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Nokia-Lumia-1020-Nokia-Phone-41MP-Camera-Dual-Core-1-5GHz-32GB-ROM-2-GB/32415650302.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.67455f99ocHZOB&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10342_10343_10059_10340_10341_10696_100031_10084_10083_10103_524_10618_10624_10307_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_43,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=a182685b-0e22-4a88-a7be-6a51dfbeac21-3&algo_pvid=a182685b-0e22-4a88-a7be-6a51dfbeac21&priceBeautifyAB=0")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
element = soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"price", "id":"j-sku-price","class":"p-price"}).text.strip()
# pattern_1 = re.compile("/d+./d+").findall(element)
# print (pattern_1)
print (element)
```

and this is the output :)

```
146.00
```

thank you every one :)